# Проблема с внедрением Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragment

Хотел добавить иконку, как описано здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/242033/. После добавления кода получил вылет приложения, пытался менять layout - не помогало. Полез в LogCat увидел такое [Скриншот](http://i004.radikal.ru/1502/27/ce5dbed3115b.png)

Поискал в гугле, ничего дельного не обнаружил

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

`` `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"> ``
`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
         />

```
<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->

<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.criterion.achieveit.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    // this is data fro recycler view
    ItemData itemsData[] = { new ItemData("Help",R.drawable.help),
            new ItemData("Delete",R.drawable.content_delete),
            //new ItemData("Cloud",R.drawable.collections_cloud),
            new ItemData("Favorite",R.drawable.rating_favorite),
            new ItemData("Like",R.drawable.rating_good),
            new ItemData("Rating",R.drawable.rating_important)};

    // 2. set layoutManger
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    // 3. create an adapter
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(itemsData);
    // 4. set adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    // 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext()));
}
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
     if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
}
```

Помогите советом или кодом

Comment: 1) Отформатируйте нормально код.    
2) Выложите стактрейс **текстом**, а не **скриншотом**    
3) Уберите лишний код, локализуйте проблему. Весь ваш код за вас править никто не собирается.    
4) Гуглите вы плохо.    
5) Выложите XML и JAVA код вашего фрагмента.

Comment: Судя по выхлопу ошибка таки в XML, там где фрагмент. Может, у вас его класса в проекте нема. Или в его разметке косяки. И, по моему опыту, пихать фрагмент XML тегом в разметку - плохая идея. Его потом оттуда сложно убрать) Лучше в рантайме добавлять.

Comment: Все прекрасно работало до того, как я внедрил Toolbar, сомневаюсь, что в разметке дело. Фрагмент там со времен создания шаблона с NavDrawer лежит